# Poliigon Question: What is the node setup required to overlay a Grunge Drips Overlay onto a Marble Material

Tags: materials

The question is in the title, I'll link images of the materials in question. Let me know if I should link the marble materials default node tree.
[image]

[image]

Comment: -1 Questions should show some research or effort, please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way to do it is to give your dirt picture a transparent background (and save it as PNG) so that you'll be able to use the alpha channel in the factor socket of a *Mix Shader*.

[image]
[image]